# NextResponse redirect doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm on a Next 13 project and I'm having a problem with the NextResponse redirect, I'm able to login correctly, but the redirect doesn't work as it should, so the cookie isn't being set thanks to the redirect malfunctioning. Here's the code:

```
const redirectUrl = new URL('http://localhost:3000/perfil').toString();

const test = NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl, {
   headers: {
     'Set-Cookie': `token=${token}; Path=/; max-age=${cookieExpiresInSeconds}`,
   },
})
```

Comment: are you able to redirect or not?

Comment: I can't redirect.

Comment: are you sure 'http://localhost:3000/perfil' is the valid url?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. The page.tsx file is inside a folder called profile, it should be like this, correct?

Comment: yes, try to navigate manually with copy/paste the url in the browser

Comment: Browsing through the browser with you normally.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/next-server)

> ### Static Methods The following static methods are available on the NextResponse class directly:
>
> redirect() - Returns a NextResponse with a redirect set
>
> rewrite() - Returns a NextResponse with a rewrite set
>
> next() - Returns a NextResponse that will continue the middleware
> chain
>
> To use the methods above, you must return the NextResponse object
> returned. NextResponse can be imported from next/server:

I think you have to return from middleware inorder to redirect:

```
return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl, {
   headers: {
     'Set-Cookie': `token=${token}; Path=/; max-age=${cookieExpiresInSeconds}`,
   },
```